# How would Aurora look like if no magnetic field was there to protect the Earth?

Tags: magnetic-field, solar-wind, pole

The greatest part of the Earth is protected from the Solar wind by its magnetic field. This field makes the wind particles (mainly protons and electrons) the beauty of Aurora appear.
Suppose the magnetic field wasn't present. The Solar wind particles hitting the southern and northern parts of our planet would distribute themselves over whole the Earth's surface.
How would Aurora look like?
For certain it would be not slowly swirling (following the slowly changing magnetic field lines). Will we see a sparkling sky? Or what?

[image]